# Заплющте/розплющте очі чи закрийте/відкрийте очі?

Tags: вживання-слів, синоніми, словосполучення

В словниках складновживаних словосполучень використовують "розплющте", але немає пояснень чому. "Відкрийте" більш милозвучно, на перший погляд, і досить часто від україномовних чую саме такий варіант.

Comment: А можете конкретизувати: про які саме словники Ви кажете?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У [словнику української мови в 11 книгах](http://sum.in.ua/s/vidkryvaty) знаходимо:

> **Відкривати (відкрити) очі** кому — показувати правду, виводити з омани. Комсомол відкрив Сашкові очі й на те, що таке дисципліна і чому вона така важлива.
>
> **[РОЗПЛЮЩУВАТИ 2](http://sum.in.ua/s/rozpljushhuvaty)**, ую, уєш, недок., РОЗПЛЮЩИТИ, щу, щиш, док., перех. Розкривати (око, очі). Розплющую очі — темно. Коло диліжанса якісь люди з ліхтарем (Степан Васильченко, I, 1959, 184)

На сайті [Мова — ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/sunonimu/zakrivati):

> **Відкривати** новий ресторан, змагання, засідання, таємницю, душу, карти, рахунок, закон фізики, комусь очі на правду
>
> **Розплющувати (заплющувати)** очі, повіки

На [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8/) вказана інформація:

> Перевірте вживання дієслова **відкривати(ся)** і в разі потреби замініть:
> **розплющувати(ся)** — про очі.

Тому правильно вживати словосполученення **заплющте/розплющте** очі, бо слова **відкрийте/закрийте** нормативно вживати з іншими словами.
**Відкрити очі** можна лише у значенні „показувати правду, виводити з омани“,
а [**закрити очі**](http://slovopedia.org.ua/49/53399/357614.html)  *заплю́щувати* (рідше *закрива́ти*, *замика́ти* і т. ін.) чи *заплю́щити* (рідше *закри́ти*, *замкну́ти* і т. ін.) *о́чі* в значенні „навмисне не помічати чого-небудь, не звертати уваги на щось“.

Отже, **закрити/відкрити очі** — можна лише у фразеологічних сполуках.

Comment: Я незгоден. П'яте значення слова «[відкрити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=12823&page=422)» і третє значення слова «[закрити](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=29959&page=985)» в СУМ. Я вважаю, що вживати можна обидві пари _(так, «розплющити»/«заплющити» точніші (вони мають менші множини значень); іще «розплющити»/«заплющити» самобутніші («відкрити»/«закрити»/«открыть»/«закрыть»/«open»/«close» кажуть майже у будь-якій мові), тож не варто дозволяти витісняти їх більш загальнішим; але одне лише це не робить пару «відкрити»/«закрити» неправильною).

Answer (score 1):

В тому ж самому словнику з 1ї відповіді є приклад вживання «відкривати очі» у Т. Шевченко (пункт 5, 2 підпункт) саме у значенні розтуляти, розплющувати.
Є й інші приклади вживання такого словосполучення в українській літературі.
Тобто можна вживати обидва варіанти!

Answer (score 0):

М. Коцюбинський зокрема *розкривав очі* ([«На віру»](https://books.google.com/books?id=o3VKDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT7&dq=%22%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%96+%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%96%22), 1891):

> Широко **розкриті очі** пильно дивились на двері, ухо пожадливо ловило кождий згук в нічній тиші і все одурювало сполохане та роз'ятрене серце.

Comment: *Вогонь палає і гуготить, а вона **заплющує** очі, хитається, і їй здається, що то шумить колосом нива і серп черкає по стеблу.*

Comment: Якби ви провели трохи аналізу, то помітили, що в цьому творі він всюди *широко розкриті*. На добру відповідь це не тягне. -1

Comment: @Yola, але ж могли б бути «широко розплющеними»… Це не аналіз, але наведення (по-моєму) значущого факту, я плюсонув.

Comment: @Sasha можливо Коцюбинський вважав, що *розкриті* можна вживати лише разом з *широко*.

Comment: @Yola, _«А як тільки в **розкриті очі** вступило зелене, що котилось буйними хвилями луків та лісу, як тільки небо спустилось і ніжно торкнулось обличчя, немов пушинка, як тільки в груди ввіллявсь золотий напій повітря, його сповила солодка втома, як у людини, що встала з смертельного ложа, і впало десь у безодню все, чим досі жив: спека роботи, вогонь небезпеки, чад крові і боротьби…»_ — теж Коцюбинський («В дорозі», 1907; хоча _широко розкриті очі_ він справді часто вживає, так).